# Is preposition "OF" required in the given sentence?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure, ellipsis

I happen to came across below stated sentence in an English preposition book.

"This photo is her with her best friend."

I assume, that grammatically correct sentence should be:

"This photo is **of** her with her best friend."

To me here **of** means:
"indicating an association between two entities, typically one of belonging, in which the first is the head of the phrase and the second is something associated with it.

I am not native English speaker. Is it something to do with AmE and BrE? or I lack understanding of sentence structure :(

Comment: Related question (but maybe not a duplicate): [Why is there “of” here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/81809/9161)

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences have the same meaning. I agree that adding "of" is more grammatical, but sometimes people omit it.

In

> This photo is her with her best friend.

"this photo" can be understood as "the content of this photo".